# Python discrete array but continually cutting

Tags: python, arrays

I have some data been draw like this :

[image]

Let's talk about only one curve .

This curve is been represented by 2 discrete array,for example:

```
for x axis : timestemp = [0,112,445,778,1000] 
for y axis : value = [12.7,22.4,77.6,22.7]
```

They are corresponding to each other one by one , like in timestamp 0 value = 12,7, timestamp is 112 the value is 22.4

I wish I could get some continues representation of the curve , then I could cut them equally by timestamp , like at 0 is 12.7,at 100 is 18.7(I just randomly pick this number because 22.4 is at time 112)

```
def window_slider(X,Y,x_step):
```

therefore when I take :

```
X=[12.7,22.4,77.6,22.7]
Y = [0,112,445,778,1000] 
x_step = 100
```

this function will return a data contain all information I could retrieve the curve exactly the same as original but been equally cut into 10 pieces .

I appreciate for any helps .. thanks

### more explanations

This question come up with I got discrete data and draw it by matplotlib in a continues form(curve)

[image]

however the data it self is still discrete represented , each point is represented by (x,y).

Now I need to cut them into particular windows ,if I take window length 5s , I wish I could get some data array to represent this

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear! can you add an expected output? and explain more about your problem and what you want to do?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sample some higher density data then you could increase the sampling to achieve the desired data granularity.

If you don't have any data to sample from then just from data points, without making any further assumptions about the nature of the data, you cannot tell what the value of the time series was.

You could have an infinite number of functions going through particular set of points and only when you make an assumption that, for example, the value of the signal measured increases or decreases linearly you would be able to get some value.

If you are looking for matches between times series you have a number of well-known methods to figure it out, like [dynamic time warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
timestemp = [0,112,445,778,1000] 
value = [12.7,22.4,77.6,22.7,33]

new_timestemp = [x for x in range(min(timestemp),max(timestemp)+1)]

steps = [ 1. * (value[t] - value[t-1]) / (timestemp[t] - timestemp[t-1]) for t in range(1,len(timestemp))]

new_value = [i+y for i in value for y in steps]

print new_value
```